# Override field twig template in views

Tags: views, 8

I am trying to override the field rendered in a view. The field name is: **this_is_field**

I copied the /core/modules/views/views-view-field.html.twig and placed it my theme folder.

I renamed with both methods below

```
views-view-field--this-is-field.html.twig
views-view-field--display-name--block-name--this-is-field.html.twig
```

I have turned on Twig debugging and still the copied template isn't working.

Am I renaming wrong?

Comment: Is that the suggestion pattern?

Comment: @Kevin What do you mean?

Comment: @pierostz updated my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It needs to be:

**views-view-field--[[field-machine-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ng7E.png).html.twig**

If you look in Manage Fields, your [field machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ng7E.png) is probably field_this_is_field.

Therefore, in your case:

**views-view-field--field-this-is-field.html**

Note that this is will override for all views that have this field, if you want to only target a specific view use:

views-view-field--[view-machine-name]--[[field-machine-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ng7E.png).html.twig

Comment: The first method worked like a charm. How about the second...meaning what is the [view-name]?

Comment: @pierostz the name of your view, if your view is called "Cool Items" then you add there `cool-items`

Comment: Ok got it working.

Comment: This answer did not work for me. To get the override working I used views-views-field--[view_name]--[display_name]--[field_name]. Note the use of underscores instead of hyphens for the view, display and field names.

Answer (score 2):

I tried second method from above answer and it didn't work. What works for me is views-view-field--[view-name]--[field-machine-name].html.twig