# Override output of taxonomy name field

Tags: views, 9

In drupal 9, the default output for a taxonomy term name field related to a specific piece of content is:

```
<element>"Item1, Item2, Item3"</element>
```

I want:

```
<element>Item1</element><element>Item2</element><element>Item3</element>
```

I there a way to do this? I can't see to target this in a theme suggestion for related taxonomy term name fields.

I only want to change the output for a specific view and display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you don't see the suggestions in Twig Debug? They are still there, see [Override field twig template in views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272954/override-field-twig-template-in-views).

You don't need to override a template, however. Views has a built-in Twig template engine. In the field settings open *Rewrite Results*
and add your HTML element:

```
<i>{{ field_foo }}</i>
```

If you want to remove the comma separator look in *Multiple Field Settings*.

Comment: Turns out I was using an indexed field so there were no multiple field settings. Swapping to the actual taxonomy term did the trick. I did not know about that way of rewriting a field. Thanks.